# Select values from table where value in comma delimited string

Tags: ms-access, select, delimited

this is my first post...
I'm busy writing up a piece of software in Access 2010. My SQL's not too bad, but I'm a little stumped here.

I have a table with the following layout

```
ID = AutoNumber, 
Category = Text, 
SubCategory = Text, 
Grades = Text.
```

And the following data

```
ID  Category    SubCategory   Grades
2   Behaviour   Good          RRR,RR,R,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
3   Behaviour   Not so Good   RRR,RR,R,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
4   Health      Doctor Note   RRR,RR,R,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
5   Social      Peer Pressure   
6   Academics   General Academic Knowledge      1,2,3
7   Academics   Additional Academic Knowledge   1,2,3
8   Gross Motor Skills  Kicks a ball that is moving towards him or her. 
9   Gross Motor Skills  Hops and jumps while in motion  R
10  Gross Motor Skills  Skips   RR
11  Gross Motor Skills  Gallops RR
12  Gross Motor Skills  Jumps forward 10 times  RR
13  Gross Motor Skills  Catches a small bounced ball    RR
14  Gross Motor Skills  Turns somersault    RR
15  Gross Motor Skills  Alternates feet walking up or down stairs   RR`
```

I'm trying to create a query where I select for eg

```
SELECT SubCategory from CATEGORY WHERE GRADES LIKE R
```

and it should return

```
Good
Not so Good
Doctors Note
Peer Pressure
Hops jumps and Skips
```

and obviously if I require Grades RRR or 1 or 2 or 5 it should select as needed

please can anyone assist.
Thanks
Warren

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the operator `LIKE` this way:

```
SELECT SubCategory 
FROM CATEGORY 
WHERE ',' + GRADES + ',' LIKE '*,R,*'
```

or if you want the queried value `'R'` separately as a parameter:

```
SELECT SubCategory 
FROM CATEGORY 
WHERE ',' + GRADES + ',' LIKE '*,' + 'R' + ',*'
```

Comment: I was so close... I used WHERE ',' & GRADES & ',' LIKE ',R,' :) which didn't work...

THANK YOU....

Comment: You missed the wild cards.